# Azure App Insights and Azure Log Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

I need to understand how the data collection , and exporting data to different applications is different in case of App Insights and Log Analytics.

They are both of part of Azure Monitor? Do they work against the same data?

What is the duration of data stored and cost implications of using them?

I wanted to know the latest update on these services as the same question has been asked before but no answer is marked as accepted and is very old-I believe Azure has changed a lot after that.

Comment: For retention and costs see [the pricing docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/monitor/)